# How to generate a specific time of clock in "C" programming

Tags: c, time, clock

For example, the following are sample runs of the program:

```
Enter the hour: 5

Enter the minute: 23

Enter A (for AM) or P (for PM): A

Enter how many minutes to display: 5

The new time is

5:24 AM

5:25 AM

5:26 AM

5:27 AM

5:28 AM

Enter the hour: 11

Enter the minute: 57

Enter A (for AM) or P (for PM): P

Enter how many minutes to display: 4

The new time is

11:58 PM

11:59 PM

12:00 AM

12:01 AM

Enter the hour: 12

Enter the minute: 55

Enter A (for AM) or P (for PM): P

Enter how many minutes to display: 7

The new time is

12:56 PM

12:57 PM

12:58 PM

12:59 PM

1:00 PM

1:01 PM

1:02 PM
```

Also, I'm not allowed to use the folling statements:

•   break; (except when used in a switch() statement)
•   continue;
•   exit();
•   abort();
•   goto

Comment: not that we aren't still willing to help either way, but this sounds like homework?

Answer (score 2):

I will preface this by answer by stating that using the in-built C time functions is overkill for this problem, which is unfortunately the kind of intuition that you only gain from experience.

---

From the problem statement, you can deduce that you require a "time" value that can represent 24 hours worth of time, at one minute granularity.  The operations required on this time value are:

- Set the value to a time provided by the user, as an "hour" value, a "minute" value, and an "AM/PM" value;
- Output the value in the format "11:58 PM";
- Add a minute to the time value.

You now have to decide how you're going to represent the "time" value in C.  One option is to use two integers (representing the hour and the minute) and a boolean (representing AM or PM).  When you use multiple values to represent a single logical value, it's conventional to wrap those into a `struct`, so our "time" type might look like:

```
struct time_of_day {
    int hour; /* From 1 to 12 */
    int minute; /* From 0 to 60 */
    int is_pm; /* 0 or 1 */
};
```

(In this case we've followed the convention that an `int` is used to store a boolean value).

You now have to figure out how to implement the three operations above using this representation of a time.  With this representation, the first operation *Set the value to a time provided by the user* becomes very easy: you simply need to check that the hour and minute values provided are in the correct range, then store them directly in the `hour` and `minute` members of the `struct time_of_day`.  You then need to set the `is_pm` value to `0` if the user entered "AM", or `1` if the user entered "PM".

The second operation *Output the value* is also quite simple: you can directly use the `printf()`, if you know these hints:

- The `printf` format specifier `%.2d` will print an integer padded to two places;
- The expression `is_pm ? "PM" : "AM"` will evaluate to `"PM` if `is_pm` is true, and `"AM"` if it is not.

The third operation, *Adding a minute* to the time value, can be broken down like this:

- Add 1 to the minute part of the time;
- If the minute part is now less than 60, stop;
- Set the minute part to 0 and add 1 to the hour part of the time;
- If the hour part is now less than 12, stop;
- If the hour part is now 12, change from AM to PM or PM to AM and stop;
- Set the hour part to 1.

An additional hint for this part:

- The expression `is_pm = !is_pm` will change `is_pm` from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

Comment: If hours roll over to 1, the maximum hour should be 12, and so no further modifications should occur if the hour is 12.

Comment: @jwodder: The change from AM to PM and vice-versa happens at the `11:59` -> `12:00` transition, not the rollover from 12 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the simplest method is to use `strftime()`, see [MSDN details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  You'll have to manually do the multiple time outputs, but it's a simple enough process once you've filled in the tm struct.